# Express: rawBody / buffer on a single route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I need to grab the rawBody (buffer) for a POST request, but I only need to do this on a single route in my application.

Currently, I'm using the following in my main `app.js`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: function(req, res, buf) { req.rawBody = buf; }}));
```

This works, but it is sending the buffer for every route. This is undesirable because it uses twice the RAM for every request in my app.

How can I instead obtain the rawBody on the single route I need it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you'd create that single route and inline the middleware:

```
app.post('/route', bodyParser.json(...), function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Followed by the "normal" setup:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/another-route', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Instead of abusing `bodyParser.json()`, you could also consider using [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions).

Answer (score 0):

If its trivial to refer to the specific route then this would work.This is a very simplistic representation of the idea:

```
var routeIWantToBuffer = "someroute";
app.use(bodyParser.json(
  {
    verify: function(req, res, buf) { 
      if(req.route === routeIWantToBuffer) req.rawBody = buf;
    }
  }
));
```

Usually route/use functions also have a `next` argument which is used to continue the chain. I'm not saying this is wrong, but I don't know what the rest of your code looks like. But I would expect it to look like this:

```
var routeIWantToBuffer = "someroute";
app.use(bodyParser.json(
  {
    verify: function(req, res, buf, next) { 
      if(req.route === routeIWantToBuffer) req.rawBody = buf;
      next();
    }
  }
));
```